# Selective Sub Directory Deleting

Tags: linux, bash, directory, find

So far i have this script. 
my folder structure for now is /root/test/
inside test a folder gets created each month named May Jun July based on (date +%B)

i want the script to delete all sub directory's minus the directory that matches this months (date +%B) and keeping its contents.

currently it deletes everything apart from the sub directory matching.  May is completely empty.  any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash

LinkDest=/root/test
m_date=$(date +%B)

find $LinkDest/ -not -name May -xdev -depth -mindepth 1 -exec rm -Rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
find $LinkDest/ -not -path "*$m_date*" -xdev -depth -mindepth 1 -exec rm -Rf '{}' \;
```

Comment: is it possible to add two paths to ignore... "*$m_date*,*full*"

Comment: Yes sure you can do: `find $LinkDest/ -not -path "*$m_date*" -not -path "*$p_date*"`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `find` without the `-exec` to see what's going to be removed. The problem is that `-name` tries to match the whole name, not a part of it. You need `-path`:

```
find -not -path "*/$m_date" -not -name $m_date
```